# Laravel : how to get the value when you submit/store into database

Tags: php, laravel

When i tried to submit the booking form like this :

```
How many book : 2
```

```
Name : a
email : a@gmail.com

email#1 : b@gmail.com
```

In the database :

```
ID : 1
Name : a
Email : a@gmail.com
Other email : NULL

ID : 2
Name : NULL
Email : NULL
Other email : b@gmail.com
```

How can i make the value of name, and email at ID number 2 is not null
But instead is

```
ID : 2
Name : a
Email : a@gmail.com
Other email : b@gmail.com
```

The Controller :

```
$firstName = $booking->first_name;
        $lastName = $booking->last_name;
        foreach ($request->input('other_emails') as $email){
            Booking::create([
                'first_name'=>$firstName,
                'last_name'=>$lastName,
                'other_emails'=>$email
            ]);
            Mail::to($email)->send(new OthersEmail($isi_email1));
        }
```

The model :

```
protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'other_emails'    
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You must update your data.

```
Booking::where('ID',2)->update([
  'first_name'=>$firstName,
  'last_name'=>$lastName,
  'other_emails'=>$email
])
```